# Return the most recent date after comparing dates from array list in Java

Tags: java, datetime, arraylist, comparator

How do I return the most recent date after comparing all the elements in the Array List? The expectation is to return `2023-01-03T02:00:00.800Z` value as it is the most recent date in the list out of all the elements. Could anyone please help?

I created a working example using [JDoodle](https://www.jdoodle.com/iembed/v0/NF2)

**Code**

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Car {
  String name;
  String sold;
  Car(String name, String sold) {
    this.name = name;
    this.sold = sold;
  }
}
public class MyClass {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    ArrayList <Car> carsList = new ArrayList <Car> ();

    carsList.add(new Car("BMW", "2023-01-01T02:00:00.800Z"));
    carsList.add(new Car("Jeep", "2023-01-02T02:00:00.800Z"));
    carsList.add(new Car("Benz", "2023-01-03T02:00:00.800Z"));

    for (int i = 0; i < carsList.size(); i++) {
      for (int j = i + 1; j < carsList.size(); j++) {
        int res = carsList.get(i).sold.compareTo(carsList.get(j).sold);
        System.out.println(res);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I like the `SequencedCollection` answer below - about as up-to-date as it gets. As others have said, you should use a proper `java.time` type for your sold date, but since you use proper ISO formats, you can sort as strings with `Car latestSold = carsList.stream().max(Comparator.comparing(Car::getSold)).orElseThrow();`

Comment: Assuming there is at least one car in the list and that `sold` is an `Instant` or other date-time object as in a couple of the answers: `Collcetions.max(carList, Comparator.comparing(Car::getSold))` gives you the most recently sold car.

Comment: Yes, better still ;)

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you declare `sold` as an `Instant`. However, if you want to keep it as a `String` for some reason, you can parse it into an `Instant`. Note that your date-time strings are already in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format; therefore, you do not need to use a `DateTimeFormatter` in order to parse them.

```
carsList.stream()
        .max(Comparator.comparing(car -> Instant.parse(car.sold)))
        .get()
        .sold
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/rNVvEP)

Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**

Comment: For a real *date/time* (in opposite to a *timestamp*) never use `Instant` but `ZonedDateTime`. For UTC, both are freely interchangeable, but timestamp never has a timezone – something that is mandatory for a date/time value. Technically (for the purpose here) it does not make much of a difference, but semantically, it is important to distinguish both *timestamps* and *date/time* values.

Comment: @tquadrat I agree in making that distinction. I took the `sold` strings in the question to be instants rather than dates and times exactly because they all happen to be in UTC. The question does not inform us of any tome zone/s. The OP knows best, and your comment is useful, thanks.

Comment: @tquadrat Maybe going off a tangent, if a car parked in Chicago is traded from a seller i Denver to a buyer in New York through a server in California, which time zone would be relevant? My first shot would be storing the instant and then converting to each time zone as needed.

Comment: @OleV.V. – If you use `ZonedDateTime`, you use the timezone that you want to use: it is part of the date/time value. And as said: the difference is semantically, not technically: a `ZonedDateTime` can be moved easily to any other desired time zone, too, but different from an `Instant` without changing the data type – because an `Instant` does not have a time zone  (that it is the same as UTC does not give it a time zone, despite the `Instant::toString` prints one).

Comment: @tquadrat Your "timestamp" point is pedantic. A timestamp can only be defined within the context of a time zone or offset.  The timestamp concept in *java.time* is defined via the `Instant` class as a count of seconds plus a count of nanoseconds since the first moment of 1970 ***as seen with a zero offset from UTC***. Ignoring the "UTC" in that definition is incorrect, useless, and rather silly.

Comment: @BasilBourque – you may have a second look on the definition given by you, than you will find the error. A timestamp does not have a time zone, because it is explicitly said to be UTC. We can also discuss now whether UTC is a timezone, but that would lead to the point why UTC is treated as a time zone, and why `Instant::toString` prints the Zulu at the end. The polite version would be: it simplifies things, although it raises discussions from time to time.

Answer (score 3):

Other Answers are correct. But here is some alternate syntax, and use of correct date-time type. And we see the new `SequencedCollection` features in Java 21+.

## tl;dr

Define your class as a record that implements `Comparable`.

```java
record CarSale( String name , Instant whenSold ) implements Comparable < CarSale >
{
    private static final Comparator < CarSale > COMPARATOR =
            Comparator
                    .comparing ( CarSale :: whenSold )
                    .thenComparing ( CarSale :: name );

    @Override
    public int compareTo ( final CarSale other )
    {
        return CarSale.COMPARATOR.compare ( this , other );
    }
}
```

Define your resulting sorted collection as a `SequencedCollection` whose implementation is a `TreeSet`. Get the latest car sale by getting the last element of the collection.

```java
CarSale latest =
        new TreeSet <> (
                List
                        .of (
                                new CarSale ( "BMW" , Instant.parse ( "2023-01-01T02:00:00.800Z" ) ) ,
                                new CarSale ( "Benz" , Instant.parse ( "2023-01-03T02:00:00.800Z" ) ) ,
                                new CarSale ( "Jeep" , Instant.parse ( "2023-01-02T02:00:00.800Z" ) )
                        )
        )
                .getLast ( );  // Java 21+.
```

> CarSale[name=Benz, whenSold=2023-01-03T02:00:00.800Z]

## Details

### Naming

Your names are a bit vague. The `sold` could be more clear such as `whenSold`. And `Car` class is really about when a car was sold. So `CarSale` would be more precise.

### Record

If the main purpose of your `Car` class is to transparently communicate shallowly-immutable data, define your class as a [record](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395). The compiler implicitly creates the constructor, getters, `equals` & `hashCode`, and `toString`.

```java
record CarSale ( String name , String whenSold ) {}
```

### `java.time.Instant`

That second parameter, `whenSold`, represents a moment, a point on the timeline. Java includes the *java.time* classes for such date-time work. Use [`java.time.Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) to represent a point on the timeline as seen in UTC (an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds).

```java
record CarSale ( String name , Instant whenSold ) {}
```

Your input strings use standard ISO 8601 format to represent that moment. The *java.time* classes by default use ISO 8601 formats when parsing/generating text. So we can directly parse your inputs.

```java
CarSale car = new CarSale ( "BMW" , Instant.parse( "2023-01-01T02:00:00.800Z" ) ) ;
```

### `List.of`

You can collect your instantiated `CarSale` objects more compactly with [List.of](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#of(E,E,E)).  This produces an [unmodifiable `List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#unmodifiable) object.

Your example data is already in the desired sort order. So I changed your original order so we can verify sorting is happening.

```java
List < CarSale > carSales =
        List.of (
                new CarSale ( "BMW" , Instant.parse ( "2023-01-01T02:00:00.800Z" ) ) ,
                new CarSale ( "Benz" , Instant.parse ( "2023-01-03T02:00:00.800Z" ) ),
                new CarSale ( "Jeep" , Instant.parse ( "2023-01-02T02:00:00.800Z" ) ) 
        );
```

### `Comparable`

Other Answers apply a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html). That is a valid approach. But if your primary default way to sort these `CarSale` records is by `whenSold`, then build that into your class as a feature. To build that in, implement the [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface with its `compareTo` method.

To implement `compareTo`, we can define a contained `Comparator` to do the work. Make it `static` to have a [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) [constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_(computer_programming)).

When sorting on `whenSold`, we could have a tie when two or more cars are sold at the same moment. To break the tie, we can look at the only other property, `name`.

```java
private static final Comparator < CarSale > COMPARATOR =
        Comparator
                .comparing ( CarSale :: whenSold )
                .thenComparing ( CarSale :: name );
```

Finish the `compareTo` method.

```java
@Override
public int compareTo ( final CarSale other )
{
    return CarSale.COMPARATOR.compare ( this , other );
}
```

### Sorting

Finally, we get to the sorting.

We have an unmodifiable list, which cannot be sorted. So we need to create a modifiable collection that can be sorted. We can do that by passing the unmodifiable list to the constructor of a modifiable `List` implementation.

```java
new ArrayList <> ( carSales )
```

#### `Stream` sorting

From there we can sort by making a stream, asking the stream to sort itself using the "natural order" of our `CarSale` objects. The natural order is the order determined by its being `Comparable`. We collect the resulting sorted elements into another `List`.

```
List < CarSale > carSalesSorted = new ArrayList <> ( carSales ).stream ( ).sorted ( ).toList ( );
```

#### `SequencedCollection`

In Java 21, we can use the more general interface [`SequencedCollection`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SequencedCollection.html) rather than `List`. See [*JEP 431: Sequenced Collections*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/431).

```
SequencedCollection < CarSale > carSalesSorted = new ArrayList <> ( carSales ).stream ( ).sorted ( ).toList ( );
```

#### `TreeSet` in place of `ArrayList`

At this point, we realize that we can use a different implementation of [`SequencedCollection`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SequencedCollection.html). We can use [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeSet.html) which automatically keeps its elements in sorted order. This works only if we do not care about tracking duplicate objects, as [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html) implementations like `TreeSet` forbid duplicates. We can simply pass our unmodifiable `List` to the [constructor of `TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeSet.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.util.Collection)).

```
SequencedCollection < CarSale > carSalesSorted = new TreeSet <> ( carSales );
```

To access the elements, iterate. For example, call [`java.lang.Iterable#forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach(java.util.function.Consumer)). This works because every `SequencedCollection` object is also an [`Iterable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Iterable.html) object.

```
carSalesSorted.forEach ( System.out::println );
```

When run:

```
CarSale[name=BMW, whenSold=2023-01-01T02:00:00.800Z]
CarSale[name=Jeep, whenSold=2023-01-02T02:00:00.800Z]
CarSale[name=Benz, whenSold=2023-01-03T02:00:00.800Z]
```

#### `getLast`

Determine the latest car sale by getting the last element from our `SequencedCollection`. Simply call [`getLast`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SequencedCollection.html#getLast()).

```java
CarSale latest = carSalesSorted.getLast ( );
```

> CarSale[name=Benz, whenSold=2023-01-03T02:00:00.800Z]

---

Complete code example:

```java
package work.basil.example;

import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.*;

public class CarsLedger
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        record CarSale( String name ,
                        Instant whenSold ) implements Comparable < CarSale >
        {
            private static final Comparator < CarSale > COMPARATOR =
                    Comparator
                            .comparing ( CarSale :: whenSold )
                            .thenComparing ( CarSale :: name );

            @Override
            public int compareTo ( final CarSale other )
            {
                return CarSale.COMPARATOR.compare ( this , other );
            }
        }
        List < CarSale > carSales =
                List.of (
                        new CarSale ( "BMW" , Instant.parse ( "2023-01-01T02:00:00.800Z" ) ) ,
                        new CarSale ( "Benz" , Instant.parse ( "2023-01-03T02:00:00.800Z" ) ) ,
                        new CarSale ( "Jeep" , Instant.parse ( "2023-01-02T02:00:00.800Z" ) )
                );

        //SequencedCollection < CarSale > carSalesSorted = new ArrayList <> ( carSales ).stream ( ).sorted ( ).toList ( );

        SequencedCollection < CarSale > carSalesSorted = new TreeSet <> (
                List.of (
                        new CarSale ( "BMW" , Instant.parse ( "2023-01-01T02:00:00.800Z" ) ) ,
                        new CarSale ( "Benz" , Instant.parse ( "2023-01-03T02:00:00.800Z" ) ) ,
                        new CarSale ( "Jeep" , Instant.parse ( "2023-01-02T02:00:00.800Z" ) )
                )
        );

        carSalesSorted.forEach ( System.out :: println );

        CarSale latest = carSalesSorted.getLast ( );
        System.out.println ( "latest = " + latest );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your `for` loop by:

```
String mostRecentDate = carsList.get(0).sold;

for (int i = 1; i < carsList.size(); i++) {
  String currentDate = carsList.get(i).sold;
  if (currentDate.compareTo(mostRecentDate) > 0) {
    mostRecentDate = currentDate;
  }
}
```

But to be honest, the best would be to have `sold` as `LocalDateTime` (as it is a date) and compare date using:

```
if (currentDate.isAfter(mostRecentDate)) {
    mostRecentDate = currentDate;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, we have a data set that gives date in the UTC format so cannot change it.

Comment: @codrp So?  You can convert a UTC date/time to a `ZonedDateTime` object and even convert that to a `LocalDateTime` object and back again (to `ZonedDateTime` ), the point is, there are (super useful) classes that do this work for you - personally, I'd take the `String` time stamp and convert it (at minimum) to a `ZonedDateTime` and then pass that to the `Car` - the `Car` shouldn't be accepting a `String` date value - that's a code smell IMHO - just because you've been given something doesn't mean you need to continue using - once it passes beyond the data set, it's yours

Comment: @codrp I'd also be wary of comparing a `String` which with numbers, as you may not get the results you're expecting

Comment: `LocalDateTime` would be the wrong type here. The input string represents a date with time as seen from an offset-from-UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds. A `LocalDateTime` has only two of those three pieces: a date & time, but lacks the concept of an offset (or time zone). `Instant` is actually the appropriate type here.

Comment: @BasilBourque – Nope, `Instant` is *not* the appropriate type here! It would be `ZonedDateTime`. `Instant` is a technical point in time, a timestamp, not a date/time value. But cars are sold at a date.

Comment: @tquadrat Nope. Any `ZonedDateTime` can be converted to an `Instant`, per [`toInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/chrono/ChronoZonedDateTime.html#toInstant()). Use `ZonedDateTime` only if the problem domain requires knowledge of that particular time zone. Plainly the problem domain of the Question does *not* care about the particular time zone as the example data is all in UTC (note the `Z` on the end of input strings). With no interest in a particular time zone,  a moment should be represented as `Instant`.

Comment: @BasilBourque - First, if you read the documentation for the time package, you will find the distinction between timestamps and date/times even there. Second, if we talk about "moments" why is there a time zone indicator (you have seen the Zulu)? And again: semantically, it is a date/time, not a timestamp, as cars where sold at a calendar date.

Answer (score 0):

You can stream the cars, extract the dates and find the max date like this:

```
String maxDate = carsList.stream()
    .map(car -> car.sold)
    .max(String::compareTo)
    .orElse(null); // return null if no "sold" timestamps found
```

See [live demo](https://ideone.com/w6Xb8H).

---

Your dates (which are actually timestamps) are only meaningfully comparable as Strings because they're in ISO format. It would be better and clearer to use a more appropriate type to store them, such as [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#)

Comment: @user85421 sure, but this is not "general use" code - in this case we plainly know `get()` is safe.

Comment: @OleV.V. changed to `orElse(null)`.

Comment: @user85421 changed to `orElse(null)`.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... How do I return the most recent date after comparing all the elements in the Array List? ..."*

You can utilize the *[ZonedDateTime#parse](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence))* method.
Compare *b* to *a*, to sort by most-recent date first.

```java
import static java.time.ZonedDateTime.parse;
```

```java
carsList.sort((a, b) -> parse(b.sold).compareTo(parse(a.sold)));
```

Or, in one line, with a *stream*.

```java
Car c = carsList.stream()
                .sorted((a, b) -> parse(b.sold).compareTo(parse(a.sold)))
                .findFirst()
                .get();
```

Output

```
Benz 2023-01-03T02:00:00.800Z
```

If you don't want to use a stream or a closure, you can use an *anonymous-class*.

```java
carsList.sort(new Comparator<>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Car a, Car b) {
        return parse(b.sold).compareTo(parse(a.sold));
    }
});
```